# List in List returns "Object"

Tags: javascript, list, react-native, ecmascript-6, axios

I'm working on a react native app where I'm consuming an API (Spring Boot) that returns

```
"id": 5,
    "nom": "EXP",
    "capacite": 258,
    "dateDebutExp": "25-03-2021",
    "dateFinExp": "28-04-2021",
    "status": "Ouvert",
    "surface": 285.3,
    "localisation": "34.72105,10.52369",
    "listPoints": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "coordonnees": "34.72205,10.52369"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "coordonnees": "34.72805,10.52369"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "coordonnees": "34.72405,10.52382"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "coordonnees": "34.72906,10.52352"
        }
```

The problem is that when I call the API in my react native app when I do a console.log for the response here is what I get

```
{"capacite": 258, "dateDebutExp": "25-03-2021", "dateFinExp": "28-04-2021", "id": 5, "listPoints": [[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]], "localisation": "34.72105,10.52369", "nom": "EXP", "status": "Ouvert", "surface": 285.3},
```

so listPoints is returning [Object]

Comment: Yes? That's just the `console.log` message – it's truncated at a given depth of structure. Try `console.log(data.listPoints)`...

Answer (score 1):

try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` it will stringify the nested json objects with 2 space indentation

Comment: easiest 10 SO points in my life, thank you person :D